# Is it possible to move a Tab in Flutter TabBar by Pressing-Holding-Dragging?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if it was possible to move a Tab in Flutter TabBar in RunTime by Pressing-Holding-Dragging?
If it is not possible at the moment, is it a valid feature request and should I submit an issue on their Github?

[This](https://gist.github.com/SayidHosseini/f7c7647fb2bcfd1115ce05e2b60f834b) is what I currently have.

Comment: Don't you need to do setState at the end of your onButtonPressed method? Since you are modifying your List<Widget> variables...

Comment: Here is a little snippet, it has few bugs, https://pastebin.com/Q2ubgGER keep keep playing with it. It may serve your purpose. (I'd have posted an answer fixing it. but im running little late. I'll check this later)

Comment: @Martyns, this source code is tested and it works. Though it lacks the feature I asked!

Comment: @S.SaeedHosseini But if I understood you correctly, the feature you are asking for is something that TabBar + TabBarView already does by default, swiping between the different tabs. And what I saw in your code is that the build cycle after pressing the button, doesn't have the list of widget variables initialized. To be sure you should setState at the end also or only.

Comment: @Martyns I intended not to have a TabBar at first, and that creation of the TabBar happen dynamically and when the button is pressed. Based on that, I do not see why I should initialize it at first.

Comment: any recent updates on that?

Comment: i need this to...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reoderable_tabbar](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderable_tabbar) package. It support drag and drop of tab item with other customizations. You should see a video demo of the package in the link above.

### Example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reorderable_tabbar/reorderable_tabbar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Reorderable TabBar',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const ReorderableTabBarPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ReorderableTabBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReorderableTabBarPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReorderableTabBarPage> createState() => _ReorderableTabBarPageState();
}

extension StringExt on String {
  Text get text => Text(this);
  Widget tab(int index) {
    return Tab(
      text: "Tab $this",
    );
  }
}

class _ReorderableTabBarPageState extends State<ReorderableTabBarPage> {
  PageController pageController = PageController();

  List<String> tabs = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
  ];

  bool isScrollable = false;
  bool tabSizeIsLabel = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text("Reorderable TabBar"),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Switch(
                  value: tabSizeIsLabel,
                  onChanged: (s) {
                    setState(() {
                      tabSizeIsLabel = s;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Switch(
                  value: isScrollable,
                  onChanged: (s) {
                    setState(() {
                      isScrollable = s;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: ReorderableTabBar(
            buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
            tabs: tabs.map((e) => e.tab(tabs.indexOf(e))).toList(),
            indicatorSize: tabSizeIsLabel ? TabBarIndicatorSize.label : null,
            isScrollable: isScrollable,
            reorderingTabBackgroundColor: Colors.black45,
            indicatorWeight: 5,
            tabBorderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
              top: Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) async {
              String temp = tabs.removeAt(oldIndex);
              tabs.insert(newIndex, temp);
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            tabs.add((tabs.length + 1).toString());
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: tabs.map((e) {
            return Center(
              child: ("$e. Page").text,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```